# security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException error for MR

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Whenever i m trying to execute a map reduce job to write to Hbase table i am getting the following error in the console. I am running the MR job from the user account.

ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:user cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/data1/input/Filename.csv

I did the hadoop ls, user is the owner of the file.

-rw-r--r--   1 user supergroup    7998682 2014-04-17 18:49 /data1/input/Filename.csv

All my daemons are perfectly running, if i am using hbase client api, i am able to insert.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Thanks,
KG

Comment: Can you put your job driver code in question..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the following path

Input path does not exist: **file:**/data1/input/Filename.csv

you can see that it is pointing to local filesystem not to hdfs. Try prefixing the filesystem type hdfs in the path as follows

```
hdfs://<NAMENODE-HOST>:<IPC-PORT>/data1/input/Filename.csv
```

Comment: When you ran the program earlier, A valid core-site.xml file configuration file might be missing in the classpath. If it is not there, we got to manually specify the filesytem either by prefixing hdfs filesystem in the path or setting up the property fs.defaultFS during the creation of Configuration object