# ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException in Hadoop 2.2

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using Hadoop 2.2.0. hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar are running fine on hdfs.

I have made a wordcount program in eclipse and add the jars using maven and run this jar:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-linux:~$ yarn jar Sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.vij.Sample.WordCount /user/ubuntu/wordcount/input/vij.txt user/ubuntu/wordcount/output
```

it give following error: `15/02/17 13:09:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
where applicable
15/02/17 13:09:10 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager
at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/02/17 13:09:11 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation:
PriviledgedActionException as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE)
cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output
directory hdfs://localhost:54310/user/ubuntu/wordcount/input/vij.txt
already exists
Exception in thread "main"
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory
hdfs://localhost:54310/user/ubuntu/wordcount/input/vij.txt already
exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
        at com.vij.Sample.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)`

jar is on my local system. both input and output path is on hdfs. there is no output dir exist on output path on hdfs.

please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Acctually the error is:

```
ERROR security.UserGroupInformation:PriviledgedActionException as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE)
cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output
directory hdfs://localhost:54310/user/ubuntu/wordcount/input/vij.txt
already exists
```

Delete the output file that already exists "`vij.txt`", or output to a different file.

OR try to do the following steps:

Download and unzip the WordCount source code from this link under `$HADOOP_HOME`.

```
  $ cd $HADOOP_HOME
  $ wget http://salsahpc.indiana.edu/tutorial/source_code/Hadoop-WordCount.zip
  $ unzip Hadoop-WordCount.zip
```

then , upload the input files (any text format file) into Hadoop distributed file system (HDFS):

```
$bin/hadoop fs -put $HADOOP_HOME/Hadoop-WordCount/input/ input
$bin/hadoop fs -ls input
```

Here, `$HADOOP_HOME/Hadoop-WordCount/input/` is the local directory where the program inputs are stored. The second "input" represents the remote destination directory on the HDFS.

After uploading the inputs into HDFS, run the WordCount program with the following commands. We assume you have already compiled the word count program.

```
$ bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/Hadoop-WordCount/wordcount.jar WordCount input output
```

If Hadoop is running correctly, it will print hadoop running messages similar to the following:

```
WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. 
Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the log4j.properties files.


    11/11/02 18:34:46 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 
    11/11/02 18:34:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201111021738_0001 11/11/02 18:34:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 0% reduce 0% 
    11/11/02 18:35:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 100% reduce 0% 
    11/11/02 18:35:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 100% reduce 100% 
    11/11/02 18:35:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201111021738_0001 11/11/02 18:35:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 25 
...
```

Comment: Hi, same problem exist when output to a different file and i have deleted output dir on hdfs also. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135541/security-usergroupinformation-priviledgedactionexception-error-for-mr